# Parse / Find Results in Facebook Group Graph API Result? PHP

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook users' ID in a variable, let's say $fbid. What would be the most efficient way to check to see if they are in a certain Facebook Group?

I'd prefer to check it using the Group Graph API. I can get it in JSON at the moment, but I'm not sure how to check and see if the ID is in it.

[Here's the link to the JSON](https://graph.facebook.com/140296412683062/members?access_token=2227470867%7C2.xiDQJeLH4nNH_KYx0GzXcQ__.3600.1293757200-100000247239079%7CR5hWTUciQv1XlIhldZhhnYCOMb4)

Comment: The link shows this the following:
{ "error": { "type": "OAuthException", "message": "Error validating access token." }
} Could you provide a better example?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to use [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/). Using FQL you can query the `group_member` table:

```
SELECT * FROM group_member WHERE uid = USER_ID AND gid = GROUP_ID
```